# Sorting a group of users among themselves in users table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have **users** table and I store all users (administrators, authors and normal users) in this table. I want to order authors (who writer column posts in a newspaper) among themselves. So which way should I follow? I have no idea what to do about it. Although I tried some methods. I added an "order" column to users table and I don't know what do to next. Please give me some advice. My table structure:

```
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
| id | username        | password         | order | is_author | level |
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | admin2          | pass             |     0 |         0 |     3 |
|  2 | admin1          | pass             |     0 |         0 |     3 |
|  3 | writer&admin    | pass             |     0 |         1 |     3 |
|  4 | normaluser      | pass             |     0 |         0 |     0 |
|  5 | writer          | pass             |     0 |         1 |     1 |
+----+-----------------+------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
```

**Additional info:**

Level 3 - Super Administrator
Level 2 - Editor (Only can add news and manage users)
Level 1 - Author
Level 0 - Normal users

**Why do I need is_author colunm?**

Because every editor or super administrator isn't writer. For those who both author and administrator I added a additional column, is_author.

Give me some advice.

Comment: Show the SQL you have so far.  And do you want to select only the authors, or select all users ordered by is_author?

Comment: what would be your desired output from the above given data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your approach, create 2 tables -**

1) users
2) user_role

**users table:**

```
 +----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+----------+
 | id | username        | password         | role_id (FK) | priority |
 +----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+----------+
 |  1 | admin2          | pass             |            1 | NULL     |
 |  2 | admin1          | pass             |            1 | NULL     |
 |  3 | writer&admin    | pass             |            2 | 1        |
 |  4 | normaluser      | pass             |            4 | NULL     |
 |  5 | writer          | pass             |            3 | 3        |
 +----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+----------+
```

**user_role table:**

```
 +----+---------------------------+--------+
 | id | role                      | level  |
 +----+---------------------------+--------+
 |  1 | admin                     | 1      |
 |  2 | writer and admin          | 2      |
 |  3 | writer                    | 3      |
 |  4 | user                      | 4      |
 +----+---------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the exact thing I want to know how can I custom order the authors among themselves? This custom order will be set by the administrators.

Comment: For that I guess there is no option but to add a `priority` column in `users` table

Comment: Right, remove the order column and add a priority column. The non-author users priorty is 0 and author's will be set by administrators. Thank you.

Comment: Create a field `priority` which should be `nullable`. So set `NULL` for non-author users and for rest 1,2,3... Check edits of answer.